# TextChanged event for combobox C#

Tags: c#, combobox

Basically the in the code below i am trying to loop through the array and if the current text in the combobox does not match anything in the array it will throw an error. However i cannot get it to fire on the event TextChanged event.

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
string[] SRtier1 = { "Option1", "Option2", "Option3", "Option4", "Option5" };        

private void SRcmb_tier1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Loop SRtier1 Array to ComboBox
        for (int i = 0; i < SRtier1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (SRcmb_tier1.Text != SRtier1[i])
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select one of the options provided.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Double check if your combobox if tied to your "SRcmb_tier1_TextChanged" event, in the properties window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have *wrong loop implementation*: in your code you're eager to fire the message `SRtier1.Length` times, what you want is, probably, to check the input and fire the message once:

```
private void SRcmb_tier1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Boolean found = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < SRtier1.Length; i++)
    {
        if (SRcmb_tier1.Text == SRtier1[i])
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found)
       MessageBox.Show("Please select one of the options provided.");
}
```

Better solution is to use ***Linq***:

```
   private void SRcmb_tier1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     if (!SRtier1.Any(item => item == SRcmb_tier1.Text)) 
       MessageBox.Show("Please select one of the options provided.");
   }
```

And finally, check if `SRcmb_tier1_TextChanged` is assinged to `TextChanged` of `SRcmb_tier1` as  ***von v.*** said in comments.

Answer (score 1):

check in properties window in events if u have anything in TextChanged